# Force redirect HTTP to HTTPS AWS WORDPRESS MULTISITE BITNAMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have two websites on AWS Lightsail **WORDPRESS Multisite BITNAMI** - default installation and configuration. HTTPS is already working, however, if the user uses HTTP - it also works - I would like to do automatic redirection to all configured sites.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all HTTP requests to a particular domain, specify the domain name as a static value in the rewrite rule instead of using the SERVER_NAME variable. Here’s an example of redirecting all HTTP requests to https://example.com

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress-multisite/administration/force-https-apache/